# Short scifi story about a children-only society because they killed them all

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A 2nd half of 20th century story about a society with no adults except one individual. The punch line is something like “..we killed them [the adults] all”.

Comment: It's the **same** story you asked about in [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171980/short-story-about-children-dominated-society) isn't it? You shouldn't ask the same question again. You can bring your old question back to the top by editing it, preferably by **adding more information**. I'm sure you haven't told us **everything** you remember about it. "2nd half of 20th century" is 50 years. Can you narrow it down to before 1975 or after 1975? Was the last adult a man or a woman?

Comment: Your previous version of this question gave **more** information, namely, the story was from the 60s(?) and the last adult had been kept alive "for sentimental reasons".